# Can't run mongod ***aborting after fassert() failure on mac

Tags: mongodb, macos

I was working through the mongodb installation video on Mongodb university.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WJ8m5QHvwc
I am a mac user and encountered this problem when I initially tried to run mongod command for the first time. I am a new mongodb user and I would appreciate help with this. Thank you.

Edit: The first step I took was finding the download page on google. I selected the first organic link. I did not download the cloud service. I downloaded it and installed it onto my machine. I downloaded the most recent production version. I used the mac download.

Next, after the downloading, I went into the downloads directory in my terminal to untar the file by

```
tar xvf mongodb-osx-ssl-x86_64-3.4.3.tgz
```

That expanded the tarball. I entered the directory using

```
cd mongodb-osx-ssl-x86_64-3.4.3
```

and looked around. I saw a licence, a readme, and a bin directory.

I went into the bin directory.

```
cd bin
```

Next, I looked inside the bin directory

```
ls -l
```

I saw a bunch of mongo programs. In here I found mongo (shell) and mongod (server). Now I understand that the server will put its data in /data/db by default.

Next I proceeded to make that directory. I went root in order to do this by running

```
sudo bash
```

I then ran

```
mkdir -p /data/db
chmod 777 /data
chmod 777 /data/db
```

Next, I exited the root shell. I then looked inside the bin directory.

```
    Roberts-MacBook-Air:Downloads robertchecco$ cd mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.4.3
Roberts-MacBook-Air:mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.4.3 robertchecco$ ls
GNU-AGPL-3.0        README          bin
MPL-2           THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES
Roberts-MacBook-Air:mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.4.3 
robertchecco$ cd bin
Roberts-MacBook-Air:bin robertchecco$ ls
bsondump    mongodump   mongoimport mongoreplay mongostat
mongo       mongoexport mongooplog  mongorestore    mongotop
mongod      mongofiles  mongoperf   mongos
Roberts-MacBook-Air:bin robertchecco$ ./mongod
2017-03-28T23:07:48.262-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB    starting : pid=77503 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Roberts-MacBook-Air.local
2017-03-28T23:07:48.263-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.3
2017-03-28T23:07:48.263-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: f07437fb5a6cca07c10bafa78365456eb1d6d5e1
2017-03-28T23:07:48.264-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
2017-03-28T23:07:48.264-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2017-03-28T23:07:48.264-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-03-28T23:07:48.264-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-03-28T23:07:48.264-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-03-28T23:07:48.264-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-03-28T23:07:48.264-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-03-28T23:07:48.265-0400 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
2017-03-28T23:07:48.267-0400 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Permission denied
2017-03-28T23:07:48.267-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578 at src/mongo/util/net/listen.cpp 194
2017-03-28T23:07:48.267-0400 I -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Comment: Hi soundestmammal, and welcome to Stack Overflow. On this site, the policy is that questions should be clear and understandable _even without links_. To that end, could you describe how you had installed mongodb, and paste the contents of your terminal into your question rather than linking to an external file?

Comment: Sure thing. Will do that now.

Comment: That's odd; it is reporting that it has found an existing file, _/data/db/mongod.lock_, apparently from a previous run of mongod; is this perhaps not your first run after all?

Comment: I while back I installed mongodb via homebrew. I uninstalled it not long  after.

Comment: @soundestmammal Try to remove the `/data/db/mongod.lock` file and run the command `mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair` this will help you. And after the process is completed run your server.